# how to trigger keypress event using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input box but no clickable button as such. On press of enter, another function is called.

```
<input type = text id="message" class="disp" placeholder="your code here " onkeypress="return newEvent(event)"></input>
```

However, I dont want to press enter and want to perform the same event using jquery. jQuery will populate the value inside the textbox and onkeypress event will be fired from jQuery itself to perform the same event.

Below is the js code I have written :

```
var value="my text";
 $('#message').val(value);   
    $('#message').addEventListener('keypress',function(){
        alert("key pressed")
    });
```

I want to trigger `keypress` as soon as the input value gets populated. Currently, what happening is that the value gets populated but I have to press enter after that.

Is there a way to do so ?
Thanks

Comment: Why you want to trigger on keypress event? just call the function( newEvent(event) ) inside that function which populates the value.

Comment: @AppleBud have you tried tge solution i gave?

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript or as people call it vanilla JS

```
 document.getElementById('message')
   .addEventListener('keypress',function(){ 
     // your function code
   });
```

JQuery

```
 jQuery('#message').on('keypress',function(){
  //your function code
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

replace  `$( "#message" )` with document if you want to keypress on any element

```
$( "#message" ).keypress(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling the below function you can trigger key press

```
$(function() {
  $('item').keydown();
  $('item').keyup();
  }
```

you can also try this

```
 $('item').trigger('keypress', {which: 'A'.charCodeAt(0)});
```